# T-SQL find only the columns which can be casted as INT

Tags: sql, casting, int

I need to write an SELECT statement, that has a WHERE clause, where only the rows that can be CAST as INT will be selected, not BIGINT, but INT.

Is that possible

I am on SQL Server 20**

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(column as INT) FROM TABLE
WHERE ISNUMERIC(column) = 1
```

But then I get 'The conversion of the varchar value '275949275947' overflowed an int column'

There is alot of different data in the column - but I only need the INTs

Comment: Possible put your table schema here.

Comment: Which `**` is your actual target version, I ask because 2012 introduced `TRY_PARSE`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Title says columns, question says rows. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012:

```
select try_parse('1231321313' as int)
select try_parse('234242342341231321' as int)
```

SQL Server < 2012:

```
select  case when ISNUMERIC('1231321313') = 1 
                and patindex('%[^0-9-]%', '1231321313') = 0
                and cast('1231321313' as bigint) between -2147483648 and 2147483647
                then cast('1231321313' as int) end

select  case when ISNUMERIC('234242342341231321') = 1
                and cast('234242342341231321' as bigint) between -2147483648 and 2147483647
                then cast('234242342341231321' as int) end
```

edit: to deal with potential currency values ('$23424231321', '€23424231321' etc) you could also add `patindex('%[^0-9-]%', '1231321313') = 0`

Comment: try '$234242342341231321'

Comment: `$234242342341231321` evaluates to null using the code above

Comment: then try $23424231321 :)

Comment: Damn I am on sql < 2012, so cant use try_parse, which is working perfect as I see it - your < 2012 version of the code, looks logical, but I got problems with it, cause when their is linebreaks or other characters it wont convert varchar to bigint

Comment: I'm surprised that you have found a case that will pass the `ISNUMERIC` and `PATINDEX` tests, but then fail on the `CAST`. Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: I put in an else condition also - and then its working smoothly - thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    [column] VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '1'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '154674'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '-2147483649'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2147483648'

SELECT CAST([column] as INT) FROM @TABLE
WHERE ISNUMERIC([column]) = 1
AND CAST([column] as BIGINT)>=-2147483648
AND CAST([column] as BIGINT)<=2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on MS SQL 2012+:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( A INT, B NVARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '1' ),
        ( 2, '275949275947' ),
        ( 2, 'cc' )


SELECT  CAST(B AS INT) AS B
FROM    @t
WHERE   TRY_PARSE(
        B AS INT) IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
B
1
```

Comment: That looks nice - but still get errors "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2567953
' to data type int." looks like their is a linebreak in the field

Comment: @user2199192, yes probably.  You can  check it by:

SELECT * FROM @t WHERE B LIKE N'%' +  CHAR(10) + '%' OR  B LIKE N'%' +  CHAR(13) + '%'